# How do you continue running your program after a breakpoint in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

After setting a breakpoint, I clicked on Step Over and it goes to the next line after the breakpoint. However, I would like to continue running the program instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default key shortcut is `F9`, alternatively, go to Run > Resume Program

You can also change this shortcut by going to Settings > Keymap, and changing the key for "Resume Program"

Answer (score 10):

If you did not change the default keyboard shortcuts, you can resume the program by pressing `F9`. Also, at the bottom of the Android Studio you can see the green resume button similar to the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you click on the debug button, the android virtual machine and the debugging control panel should pop out automatically on the bottom of the Android Studio. On the debugging control panel, if you look to the left corner, you will see a green arrow pointing to the right. That is the button to resume your program after any debugging actions.